# Deleting an instance of a class via a method of that class

Tags: ruby

I have a class for pieces on a board. I want to be able to delete an instance of Piece so that anything else in the program that points to that piece will just point to nil.

Here's the very basic code version of what I want to do:

```
piece = Piece.new
variable = piece
variable #=> <Piece:0x0000000xxxxxxxx>
piece.delete
variable #=> nil
```

This seems like a very basic task so I feel like I'm missing something obvious. I've tried creating a delete method for the class with "self = nil", but this returns an error ("Can't change the value of self").

So far I have just worked around this by updating the other things that point to the object in my 'delete' method, but it seems like there should be a better way.

Comment: show your Piece class also please

Comment: Well the class is 150 lines long and king of ugly so I don't think it would be very desirable to post the whole thing. I figured deleting an instance of a class is a pretty general question and the contents of the class wouldn't be very relevant, but I could post some of it if I had an idea of what might be relevant.

Comment: It isn't necessary to post the class. It's all about whether being able to change self from within the object and removing all the references to an object at single point.

Comment: @llkin Why not necessary to see the implementation ?

Comment: Well simply put, the question retains the same meaning even if he would change the class's implementation to a different one.

Comment: @llkin Still it is relevant to see. How `Piece#delete` implemented by OP. Only showing the output doesn't make any sense.

Comment: OP - see if this one help you or not. -- http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/weakref/rdoc/WeakRef.html .

Comment: @llkin Well.It seems you understood.. But not me. It is always good to put some code to explain what is working and what is not.. and what is expected.

Comment: Just to be clear, the code I posted with only the outputs is what I want, not what the actual output is as my class is currently implemented. As Illkin said, I don't really care how its done, I just want to be able to get rid of all references by simply deleting the instance.

Edit: Here's what I have in my delete method. All it does is remove the references that my 'board' and 'player' classes have to the object.
  `def delete`
    `@board.cells[@position[0]][@position[1]].set_piece(nil)`
    `@player.pieces.delete(self)`
  `end`

Comment: Not here @csmith, this should go to the original post. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible.

Firstly, Ruby is an object-oriented language, which means that all manipulation is done via messages to objects, and all that is manipulated are objects. Variables are not objects, therefore you cannot manipulate them. (The only things you can do with variables are assign a value to them and dereference them.)

And even *if* you could manipulate variables, you would still need to hunt down every single reference to the object in question and remove it, in order for the object to be eligible for "deletion" (i.e. garbage collection).

Comment: Hm. I was trying to manipulate the object by deleting it. To me, it seemed like it would make sense if you could just somehow say "this object doesn't exist any more." Then any variables that used to be pointing to it would just be pointing to nothing. No manipulation of variables involved. But if it's not possible, that answers my question. So thanks. :)